# MySql Query: optional join of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for to join another column of 'spose name' optionally, in case a person has a spouse.

Here is the table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `relativeto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `relation` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

`relation` can be either 'n' or 's'.

- if 's' then another row holds a spouse for that person, and relativeto holds the id of the spouse.
- if 'n' then no spouse for that person

I was trying this query:

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.name AS spouse 
FROM `people` T1, `people` T2 
WHERE T1.surname LIKE 'AB%' 
    AND T1.relation='s' 
    AND T1.relativeto=T2.id
```

but it will ignore people with no spouse.
I want to add also people without a spouse, and put '-' as a name for the spouse.

Could you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join and put your `T1.relation='s'` condition in `ON Clause`

```
SELECT T1.*,coalesce(T2.name,'-') AS spouse 
FROM `people` T1 left join `people` T2 
on T1.relativeto=T2.id AND T1.relation='s' 
where T1.surname LIKE 'AB%'
```

Comment: sure, but there is a limit of 15 minutes from publishing the question... now done :)